# Trouble deploying flask application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a flask application (a website) using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It all looks fine, except when I actually try out the site, I get "Internal Server Error." In the AWS log, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'." I figured that perhaps Flask, while installed on my local machine, was not getting to my elastic beanstalk environment. So I followed the AWS [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) on the subject, but even after I installed Flask in the new virtual environment (and I see it in my project folder), I got the same results.

Comment: make sure you are running your flask application when your virtual env is activated.

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file?

Comment: I do have a requirements.txt file

Comment: Shivendra Pratap Kushwaha, I think I'm doing that, but maybe I'm doing it wrong? I created the project folder and app, and then only later added eb, which is when I made the virtual environment.